# Move files matching specific date from array of servers/folders to a local folder (Powershell)

Tags: arrays, powershell, date, copy, robocopy

I'm attempting to copy all files from an array of production servers that match a specific user-entered date (to prepare for rollbacks if necessary)...here is what I have tried:

```
[string[]]$ProdServerArray = "prdserver1", "prdserver2", "prdserver3"
[string[]]$InterfaceArray = "interfacefolder1", "interfacefolder2", "interfacefolder3", "interfacefolder4", "interfacefolder5"

New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path "C:\GetFilesResults\$($date.toshortdatestring().replace("/","-"))\$search" -Force
$LocalPath = "C:\GetFilesResults\$($date.toshortdatestring().replace("/","-"))\$search"

do
{
    $date = Read-host "Enter date (MM/DD/YYYY): "
}
while ($date -as [datetime] -isnot [datetime])
$date = $date -as [datetime]
$date

$search = foreach ($ProdServer in $ProdServerArray)
{
    foreach ($Interface in $InterfaceArray)
    {
        '\\{0}\InterfaceFiles\{1}\' -f $ProdServer, $Interface
        Get-ChildItem $search -File -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $date.date} | ForEach {
        $actualSource = Split-Path $_.FullName
        $actualDest = Split-Path $_.FullName.Replace($search,$LocalPath)
        robocopy $actualSource $actualDest $_.Name /SEC }
    }
}
```

I have been successful in getting the folder structure as I need it - "\prdserver1\InterfaceFiles\interfacefolder1\", but haven't been able to get the create/modify date of the files inside these folders and copy them to my local machine.  I've attempted Copy-Item, robocopy, batch, etc., but haven't found a way to run a loop through all of these, and best case it seems to bomb out if it runs into a file or folder that doesn't match the criteria...worst case it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

While I wasn't able to fully test this, the for-each loop seemed to do it for me. The *-Recurse* paramater of **Copy-Item** seems to be the solution, along with a few other logic and syntax changes. Let me know if this solves your problem.

```
[string[]]$ProdServerArray = "prdserver1", "prdserver2", "prdserver3"
[string[]]$InterfaceArray = "interfacefolder1", "interfacefolder2", "interfacefolder3", "interfacefolder4", "interfacefolder5"


$LocalPath = New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path "C:\GetFilesResults\$($date.toshortdatestring().replace("/","-"))\$search" -Force | select -Property FullName

do
{
    $date = Read-host "Enter date (MM/DD/YYYY): "
}
while ($date -as [datetime] -isnot [datetime])
[datetime] $date = $date -as [datetime]
Write-Output $date


foreach ($ProdServer in $ProdServerArray)
{
    foreach ($Interface in $InterfaceArray)
    {
        $search = '\\{0}\InterfaceFiles\{1}\' -f $ProdServer, $Interface

          Get-ChildItem $search -File -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $date.date} |
          ForEach {
                $actualSource = Split-Path $_.FullName
                $actualDest = Split-Path $_.Replace($search,$LocalPath)
                Copy-Item -Path $actualSource -Destination $actualDest -Recurse

    }
}
```